# How to transmit "metadata" of an HTML-element to a function? / Individual ID for HTML elements created via jinja2

Tags: javascript, html, rest, web-applications, fastapi

My title might be a bit confusing...
This is my first attempt (ever) for a webapp and I got the following solution for a set of checkboxes, created within a html template for FastAPI and with Jinja2.

```
{% for name in names %}
    <input type="checkbox" id='{"box": "a", "name_id": "{{name.id}}"}' onchange=submit_me(this)>
    <input type="checkbox" id='{"box": "b", "name_id": "{{name.id}}"}' onchange=submit_me(this)>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function submit_me(box){
        data = JSON.parse(box.id)
        data["checked"] = box.checked
        
        fetch("/test", {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
    }
</script>
```

This is just a simple example of a more complex code but shows my (inexperienced) solution for the problem to get the box ("a" or "b") as well as the name (iteration of names via jinja) inside my function.
I was just wondering, if this is really a valid option or if there is a way more "standard" approach for this out there?

This is - by the way - only the "quick and dirty" solution because I was unable to call a python function via jinja and FastAPI directly (html -> python backend -> database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what an element's `id` should be used for. If you need to attach random data to an element, use the `data-` attributes. `input` elements have the `name` attribute and `value` attribute that should be used to describe the value, and the actual value. No need to stuff JSON inside `id` (which should be a unique identifier for an element in a document).

Submitting data by checking a checkbox also seems wrong (*generally*, depends on your use case) - use a `form` element if you have data you want to submit, and submit when a button is clicked.

Since you have hardcoded values (a, b), using iteration also seems a bit weird:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box_a" id="box-a" value="{{ names[0].id }}" onchange="submit_me(this);">

<input type="checkbox" name="box_b" id="box-b" value="{{ names[1].id }}" onchange="submit_me(this);">
```

However, if you have `a` / `b` stored inside your `name` object, use iteration and have a single element where you fill out the information as necessary in the tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box_{{ name.key }}" id="box-{{ name.key }}" value="{{ name.id }}" onchange="submit_me(this);">
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this helps a lot!
I will then store these data in a combination of data- and name-attribute.
The "name" object is used to create different kinds of html-objects (label for some text, normal input for text, 4 checkboxes, buttons for dropdown-selections) so I found it the best way to hardcode it once and iterate over "names" to create as many as needed. I decided to not use a form because I want to update the data in the database immediately  when changed without the need of a button click.